# How to add faces to a flat plane?

Tags: faces

Probably a very simple question but my research hasn't turned up an answer...

I have a flat plane, comprised of two faces (A Rectangle with a line down the middle separating each face).

How do I split the faces so I have eight even-sized faces on the flat-plane rectangle?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Select all and press <kbd>w</kbd>
- Then choose *"subdivide".*

Comment: Nothing happens when I select 'Subdivide' from the menu.

Comment: Are you in edit mode? Do you have all the faces and vertices selected (a)

Comment: I'm in edit mode and I have the two faces selected, yes.

Comment: Is it adding vertices? Sometimes depending on your geometry, it will add verts but not connect them to the faces.

Comment: Try creating a new plane and starting from scratch. Just add a plane. Scale on x by 2, ctrl+r for a loop cut, left click, right click, for center. a to select all, then w, subdivide. That will do it.

Comment: I think what I was looking for was 'Loop Cut' (CTRL + r). I've restarted the project. Will confirm if Loop Cut is the working method if/when I next stumble on this problem.